# laravel request file return null

Tags: php, laravel

this question have been asked many times before, I've tried all the solutions but nothing work with me

```
   "laravel/framework": "^6.0",
```

//-----

```
   <form  action="post_customer_data" id="editform" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="logo" type="file" name="logo" class="form-control  form-control-lg">

  dd($request->file('logo')); //Return Null!!!
```

in controller i use all the required packages

```
use Storage;
use File;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Comment: what is the size of the file you are trying to upload?

Answer (score 0):

What are the result if you print all the request data? Something like that:

```
dd($request->all());
```

Comment: all other fields but not the file with the name logo

Comment: It's too weird, maybe is something from php.ini, check the next settings:

file_uploads,
upload_max_filesize,
max_file_uploads

What's your configuration?

Comment: ??? nothing there i have another website all fine